# Is there a possibility to automatically convert QVariants to Python objects?

Tags: pyqt, qvariant

*PyQt 4.5.4, Python 2.6.2*

Since version 4.5.2 PyQt is able to accept any Python objects where formerly only `QVariants` were allowed. This leads to some problems:

```
>>> itemModel.data(index, Qt.EditRole)
<Product object at 0xb7ce766c>
>>> index.data(Qt.EditRole)
<QVariant object at 0xb7ce768c>
```

Is there a possibility to remove this inconsistence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PyQt 4.6, using the modern API:

> The `QVariant` class is implemented as a
>   mapped type. Any Python object can be
>   passed when a `QVariant` instance is
>   expected. When Qt returns a `QVariant`
>   then it will automatically be
>   converted to the original Python
>   object or an equivalent.  `None` is
>   interpreted as an invalid `QVariant` and
>   vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the .toPyObject() method on a QVariant. I doubt that this works for custom types, though.

Comment: It does. But really, the trouble starts as soon as the object isn't a QVariant.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I have found is converting every value to a QVariant and then back:

```
QVariant(possiblyAQVariant).toPyObject()
```

This works for QVariants and Python types.